# How to keep the proportions of the text?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need create adaptive svg with constant height. My try is here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/zy4hz51t/53/)

html:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <svg width="360" 
        height="200" 
        viewBox="0 0 360 200" 
        preserveAspectRatio="none" 
        style="width:100%">
    </svg>
</div>
```

It worked. But symbols proportions are changing when the browser width reduce. Please help make symbols proportions permanent

Comment: the reason is the `viewbox` it is an additional scaling of the content. Remove it. Add an event handler for resizing the window and set the width of the svg and redraw/fill the svg again based on the new width

Comment: Or maybe you can get the current width (in pixels) from the SVG style and used that to redraw the svg.

Comment: If you want the aspect ratio to be preserved, don't set preserveAspectRatio="none"

Comment: @rioV8 i remove viewBox and add resize event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/zy4hz51t/63/

Comment: have you looked in the DevTools - you now have hundreds of x-axis and y-axis, you don't modify the bars and first of all you don't modify the size of the svg.